# IOS Bluetooth not discover in iPhone settings page

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

We are working in Blood pressure monitor project . we have implemented GATT protocol in our device to communicate with iphone / iPad  . so far we are using Core bluetooth framework to communicate with our device ,Its working fine in data transmitting.

But our device is not visible / listing  in iPhone Bluetooth in the settings page.
please note that we are not using any MFI chip.

Please advice what we needs to be done to make our device visible in iphone's bluetooth settings page without using MFI chip.

Comment: If you are using Bluetooth Low-Energy, it shouldn't appear in Settings.app except once you paired with it.

Comment: Yes ,we are using BLE...Kindly suggest me how to achieve my device listing  in settings page and not in inside of my app

Comment: The only way to make your device listing in settings page is to use Classic Bluetooth.

Comment: Scan, show results, and have the user connect/disconnect in the app not connect in the phone's Settings. It makes things a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your BLE device to show up in iOS Bluetooth settings, it has to have gone through the pairing process, as stated by Larme.

To do so, the device must have one or more characteristics that are encrypted. When your app tries to read/write/indicate on that characteristic, the read will fail with an Insufficient Authentication error code, which will then should start the pairing process. See section 25.10 in Apple's Accessory Design Guidelines - https://developer.apple.com/accessories/Accessory-Design-Guidelines.pdf

Once the user has selected to Pair in the dialog, keys are exchanged to finish the pairing process. Your device will show up in Bluetooth settings at that point.

Is there a specific reason that you want the device to show up in Bluetooth settings?